# Can we Undo Flags?

Tags: support, feature-request, flagging

I flagged a question thinking that it deserved it, but later I realised that the **flag** wasn't needed. So my question is can we **undo a flag**?

Comment: [Discussion on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no, you can't. But there aren't really any consequences to casting a flag that turns out not to be needed. If the flag is declined, you might see a notice next time you cast a flag that prompts you to look at why it was declined, but that's about it.

People who *consistently* and *frequently* cast invalid flags may face some consequences, but you'd really have to be trying to run into that situation.